# Meaning of "as merry a band of children as I had ever seen before or since"

Tags: adjectives

> *The long awaited moment at last came and we set out for station, **as merry a band of children as I had ever seen before or since***.

What is the meaning of the highlighted text? I think it means *We were as happy as a band of children that we have never been before or since.*

Am I right?

Comment: Your "revised" version is *grammatically* valid, but *semantically* it wouldn't actually make sense in any context I can imagine. It's fine to make a comparison to something unknown in a usage such as *Look at this! It's like nothing [that] you've ever seen before!*, but that's not really the same construction.

Comment: ...The actual cited text is just a dated / poetic way of saying *neither before nor since have I ever seen a band of children more merry than we were at that moment.*

Answer (score 1):

> "..as merry a band of children as I had ever seen before or since".

Your evaluation is correct, in this instance "merry" means "*happy*".

The word is used less frequently in modern English than perhaps it once was, except perhaps at Christmas. It is sometimes used idiomatically to describe someone who is *slightly drunk*.

Its use in your example though is also idiomatic because it appears alongside the term "*band*" (meaning group), and "*merry band*" is a recognisable old-fashioned term that is sometimes used. I suspect it may be a reference to the legend of *Robin Hood and his band of merry men*.

So in its entirety it means that the writer has never seen such a happy group of children before; that is to say they were the happiest children he had ever seen, not the happiest that he had seen that particular group.